# How to avoid checking authorization header for ReadOnly Modelviewset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a view with the following permission

```
permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
```

the permission definition is

```
class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # the object has a owner attribute
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

It listing of the objects works as expected if the user authenticated and pass correct access token. it also works if I do not add `Authorization` in header.

The only problem happens when the authorization token is expired or wrong. It sends 401 response.

```
Invalid token header. No credentials provided.
```

How can I ignore authorization token in django code for right or wrong authorization header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to achieve what I intend. However, I am not sure whether this is the standard or not. override perform_authentication in Modelviewset does the work and we can strip the authorization from the header.

```
def perform_authentication(self, request):
    if 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' in request.META:
        request.META.pop('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
```

Comment: what about you have 20 viewsets?

Comment: You can make a base viewset and extend.